# Removing unnecessary JSON spaces

Tags: ios, json, swift, codable, jsonencoder

I have encoded a `Codable` object:

```
let encodedData = try JSONEncoder().encode(someObject)
```

And I print the JSON by doing the following (I know its not safe, I'm just testing):

```
let json = try! JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: encodedData)
print("JSON:  \(json)")
```

My JSON has lots of spaces. I want a way to remove these spaces, to save space on the encoded String. You can tell that it looks quite different from a normal JSON due to these spaces.

`JSON` (part of it):

[image: JSON format]

How can I reduce the spaces to reduce the bytes this takes up?

Comment: That does not print the JSON. You convert the JSON data back to a dictionary and what you see is the description of an NSDictionary. – To see the JSON, use `print(String(data: encodedData, encoding: .utf8)!)`

Comment: @MartinR If you add it, I will accept it as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As `@Martin R` pointed out, I was not printing the JSON properly. It should have instead been:

```
let jsonString = String(data: encodedData, encoding: .utf8)!
print(jsonString)
```

The result looks like so:

```
{"type":1,"modifiers":[],"parameters":{ ...
```

This printed data can then be decoded in the future like so:

```
let data = Data(jsonString.utf8)
let someResult = try JSONDecoder().decode(SomeType.self, from: data)
```